# Extract value from a list of lists and add to new column

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

I have a data frame with one column that is a list of lists containing address information.

My data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['location1', [(123, 'Number'),('Main', 'Street'),('New York', 'City')]], ['location2', [('Broadway', 'Street'),('New York', 'City'),(11111, 'ZIP')]], ['location3', [(987, 'Number'),('Grand', 'Street'),('Chicago', 'City'), (55555,'ZIP')]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Location', 'Address_Info'])
```

This creates a data frame that looks like:

```
    Location    Address_Info
0   location1   [(123, 'Number'), ('Main', 'Street'), ('New York', 'City')]
1   location2   [('Broadway', 'Street'), ('New York', 'City'), (11111, 'ZIP')]
2   location3   [(987, 'Number'), ('Grand', 'Street'), ('Chicago', 'City'), (55555, 'ZIP')]
```

I need to extract the list that has the "Number" value in it. Then I need the numbers from that list added to the data frame in a new column.

The resulting data frame would look like this:

```
    Location    Address_Info                                                                 Number
0   location1   [(123, 'Number'), ('Main', 'Street'), ('New York', 'City')]                  123
1   location2   [('Broadway', 'Street'), ('New York', 'City'), (11111, 'ZIP')]               NaN
2   location3   [(987, 'Number'), ('Grand', 'Street'), ('Chicago', 'City'), (55555, 'ZIP')]  987
```

One of the problems I am running into is when there is no list in "Address_Info" that contains "Number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and the `str` accessor:

```
df['Address_Info'].apply(lambda l: [i[0] for i in l if i[1] == 'Number']).str[0]
```

output:

```
0    123.0
1      NaN
2    987.0
```

To save it in a new column:

```
df['Number'] = (df['Address_Info']
                  .apply(lambda l: [i[0] for i in l if i[1] == 'Number'])
                  .str[0]
               )
```

*NB. if you expect several numbers, you can leave out the `.str[0]`, then you'll get a list of the numbers (empty if nothing):*

```
df['Address_Info'].apply(lambda l: [i[0] for i in l if i[1] == 'Number'])
```

output:

```
0    [123]
1       []
2    [987]
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare the data before you create the DF

```
def get_number(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if x[1] == 'Number':
            return x[0]
    return None

data = [['location1', [(123, 'Number'),('Main', 'Street'),('New York', 'City')]], ['location2', [('Broadway', 'Street'),('New York', 'City'),(11111, 'ZIP')]], ['location3', [(987, 'Number'),('Grand', 'Street'),('Chicago', 'City'), (55555,'ZIP')]]]
for entry in data:
    entry.append(get_number(entry[1]))
print(data)
# now you can create the DF
```

output

```
[['location1', [(123, 'Number'), ('Main', 'Street'), ('New York', 'City')], 123], ['location2', [('Broadway', 'Street'), ('New York', 'City'), (11111, 'ZIP')], None], ['location3', [(987, 'Number'), ('Grand', 'Street'), ('Chicago', 'City'), (55555, 'ZIP')], 987]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode the list into rows then expand tuples into columns and keep only rows with `Number`.

```
df['Number'] = df['Address_Info'].explode() \
                                 .apply(pd.Series) \
                                 .rename(columns={0: 'value', 1: 'key'} \
                                 .query('key == "Number"')['value']
```

```
>>> df
    Location                                       Address_Info Number
0  location1  [(123, Number), (Main, Street), (New York, City)]    123
1  location2  [(Broadway, Street), (New York, City), (11111,...    NaN
2  location3  [(987, Number), (Grand, Street), (Chicago, Cit...    987
```